# aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientConnectorError with Discord bot using Docker-compose and Lavalink

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, discord, discord.py

I'm making a Discord bot in python, and I get an error when my bot tries to connect with lavalink. I use Docker-compose for the bot and lavalink, and my lavalink client is wavelink. I have checked that lavalink is on the right port.

Does anyone have any idea what's wrong?

My `docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
version: "3.9"

services:
  bot:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    restart: on-failure
    depends_on:
      lavalink:
        condition: service_started

  lavalink:
    container_name: lavalink
    image: fredboat/lavalink:master
    volumes:
      - ./Lavalink/application.yml:/opt/Lavalink/application.yml
    ports:
      - 2333
    restart: always
```

My `music.py`:

```
class Music(commands.Cog, wavelink.WavelinkMixin, name="music"):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client
        self.fancy_name = "Music"

        if not hasattr(client, 'wavelink'):
            self.client.wavelink = wavelink.Client(bot=self.client)

        self.client.loop.create_task(self.start_nodes())
    

    async def start_nodes(self):
        await self.client.wait_until_ready()

        await self.client.wavelink.initiate_node(host='127.0.0.1',
                                            port=2333,
                                            rest_uri='http://127.0.0.1:2333',
                                            password="pass",
                                            identifier='MAIN',
                                            region='us_central')
```

And my error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/wavelink/websocket.py", line 76, in _connect
     self._websocket = await self._node.session.ws_connect(uri, headers=self.headers, heartbeat=self._node.heartbeat)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 721, in _ws_connect
     resp = await self.request(method, url,
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 480, in _request
     conn = await self._connector.connect(
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 523, in connect
     proto = await self._create_connection(req, traces, timeout)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 858, in _create_connection
     _, proto = await self._create_direct_connection(
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 1004, in _create_direct_connection
     raise last_exc
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 980, in _create_direct_connection
     transp, proto = await self._wrap_create_connection(
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 943, in _wrap_create_connection
     raise client_error(req.connection_key, exc) from exc
 aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientConnectorError: Cannot connect to host 127.0.0.1:2333 ssl:default [Connect call failed ('127.0.0.1', 2333)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your bot container needs to connect to `http://lavalink:2333`, not itself on `127.0.0.1`

Answer (score 0):

You mapping is wrong you declared the port but didn't mapped it to you localhost port.
change this

```
 ports:
      - 2333
```

to

```
ports:
    - "2333:2333"
```

this will map the port from your docker container running lavalink to your localhost port `2333` or you can assign anyport you want.

ports:

- "first_arg:second_arg"
  first : localhost port
  second: docker container port

Comment: The code is running in a container, not on the host. Therefore port mappings don't matter